# Upgrade to Rhythmbox 2.99.1 in Xubuntu

Tags: installation, xubuntu, ppa, rhythmbox

I'd like to get the updates of rhythmbox for xubuntu but am really struggling to work out how.
I've tried directly installing the deb from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gnome_3/raring/main/base/rhythmbox) but it gives an error about breaking package dependency with rhythmbox-mozilla (currently 2.98).
I've tried adding PPAs but nothing seems to happen.
I downloaded the zip file, unpacked it and did ./configure but get "no such file or directory" - configure is there but it's configure.ac - is this a xfce/thunar vs nautilus/gnome problem? Will it not work with xubuntu?

Any tips gratefully appreciated. Installing experiemental things in x/ubuntu is so unbelievably complicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gnome3 ppa has rb 2.99 packages for raring, they can be installed without needing to upgrade any add. non Rb packages from the ppa.
(upgrading completely using that ppa will currently cause issue with a unity session in 13.04

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade rhythmbox

sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 && sudo apt-get update

From here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146418&p=12656513